# iOS 6 Collection View

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

I love those collection views Apple introduced in iOS6 SDK. But my iPad is not getting an upgrade to 6.0, so theres a question. If I set the deployment target to 5.1, will I be able to use those new GUI elements they added in 6.0? Or do I have to code something like a Collection View myself?

Comment: iOS6 is under NDA. You can't talk about these things to the general public. You have Apple's Developer forum for this.

Comment: [here](http://rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2013/03/uicollection-view-in-ios-6-tutorial.html) is the easy tutorial for collection view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView).

> Open Source, 100% API compatible replacement of UICollectionView for iOS4.3+

Comment: Looks like a simple and compatible replacement (uses native UICollectionView automatically for iOS6).

Answer (score 5):

`UICollectionView` class is only available for iOS 6.0 or later. You have to set the deployment target to 6.0 (or later) in order to use it. Xcode 4.5 or later supports iOS 6 development.

Answer (score 3):

Building on what ohho said, you don't have to build for 6.0 and later to use this, you can use it if it's available by checking the presence of the class at runtime, you can still set your deployment target to say 4.3.

All this means is that you must check at runtime if you have the `UICollectionView` class. If you don't then you must do whatever you did before, I usually used `AQGridView`.

To find out how to check at runtime for a class and or feature, please check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12590035/662605