# Conditional support of iOS 6 features in an iOS 5 app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone-5

How can you support features of iOS6 in an app with a `Minimal Deployment Target` set to iOS 5.0?

For example, if a user has iOS 5 he will see one `UIActionSheet`, if the user has iOS 6 he will see a different `UIActionSheet` for iOS 6? How do you do this? 
I have Xcode 4.5 and want an app running on iOS 5.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should always prefer detecting available methods/feature rather then iOS versions and then assuming a method is available.

See [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html).

For example, in iOS 5 to display a modal view controller we would do something like this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

In iOS 6, the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method of `UIViewController` is Deprecated, you should use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` in iOS 6, but how do you know when to use what?

You could detect iOS version and have an if statement dictate if you use the former or latter but, this is fragile, you'll make a mistake, maybe a newer OS in the future will have a new way to do this.

The correct way to handle this is:

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{/* done */}];
else
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

You could even argue that you should be more strict and do something like:

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{/* done */}];
else if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:)])
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
else
    NSLog(@"Oooops, what system is this !!! - should never see this !");
```

I'm unsure about your `UIActionSheet` example, as far as I'm aware this is the same on iOS 5 and 6. Maybe you are thinking of `UIActivityViewController` for sharing and you might like to fallback to a `UIActionSheet` if you're on iOS 5, so you might to check a class is available, see [here](http://www.lukessandbox.com/2012/checking-for-objective-c-class-availability.html) how to do so.

Comment: You can link to the framework in the project settings, in such a case that the framework may not be present on all versions, like your case, you simply set the include to be optional rather then required. ---- the question was deleted.... question/comment.

Comment: @Daniel: How does one know on which methods to use `respondsToSelector`? Or one should do it with each method call?

Comment: `respondsToSelector:` will check availability of the method you pass to it on the receiver. So generally you will call this on the method you want to call. Sometimes you will call multiple methods which are part of the same iOS version/spec, so checking one you can assume the other are available.